# Manipulating DOM from View in Angular 2

Tags: angular

The well-known blog site [medium.com](https://blog.medium.com/highlight-responses-and-multiple-drafts-now-in-the-medium-ios-app-8c70d1f50fc6#.qucc8koo4) has a highlight feature that allows its users to highlight text in the view. Highlighted text can be acted upon in a multitude of ways, from commenting on it to sharing it. Highlighting text in the view appears to wrap the highlighted string in `<span>` tags and attribute classes to the element.

Put simply, would something similar to this be possible purely in Angular 2? If so, in a general sense, how would you go about achieving this?

If this question is too broad, it may be helpful to ask if portions of strings within elements can be isolated in such a way using `on-click`.

**Update:**

@Tim Consolazio, your comment led me to the documentation for [getSelection()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getSelection) and from there I was able to find an implementation of it for Angular 2 [here](http://blog.sodhanalibrary.com/2016/10/get-highlightedselected-text-using.html#.WJkQW_ErKUk). It's important to point out that `selection` is no longer supported as a property of `document`, but that isn't important in my specific use case because my selection will only ever be text.

Comment: Sure I'd say it wouldn't be too hard. The secret for grabbing selectedText is out there (https://www.codeproject.com/articles/292159/javascript-code-to-get-selected-text for example), and otherwise you'd just have to get the mouse coords and put your overlay component where you want it. Click the overlay (share button, whatever), get the selected text in the handler, and do your thing.

Comment: From the official Angular2 tutorial - [Build a simple attribute directive](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/attribute-directives.html#!#write-directive). Their tutorial example is how to highlight using a directive. I am sure you can copy/paste this and then extend it as you see fit.

Comment: Actually I just tried a quick naive test, you put an ondblclick handler on your div or p or whatever. When you double click to select a word (you could do it with selecting a range too, I just did this quick): return window.getSelection ( ).toString ( ). It returns the selected text. Now you just plunk your widget at the mouse coords of the click and you're more or less done, submit it to a dictionary lookup, whatever. A great question I've never implemented a widget like that, now I see it's pretty easy.